# Specialize only constructor in template, keeping best performance and neat interface

Tags: c++, performance, templates, template-specialization

**1. Is it possible to just specialize a constructor in a templated class?**

I have this example:

```
// squared matrix class
template <unsigned int size>
class Matrix {
public:
    // list of lists matrix constructor
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>> values);

    // actual static data
    float data[size][size];
};
```

So basically I can instantiate squared matrices of any size by using nested initializer lists, like in:

```
Matrix <3> Identity {
    {1.,0.,0.},
    {0.,1.,0.},
    {0.,0.,1.}
};
```

Now I would like to provide **just for 3x3 matrices** a constructor that takes 3 3D vectors (`Vec3` class in my code) and uses them as the matrix's columns to build a 3x3 matrix.

Is there a way of just specializing the constructor?

If I specialize the entire class, like in:

```
template <>
class Matrix<3> {
public:
    // build matrix providing 3 Vec3 (your basis) which will be the columns
    Matrix(std::initializer_list<Vec3> basis_vectors);
};
```

Then I get errors inside the ctor definition:

```
Matrix<3>::Matrix(std::initializer_list<Vec3> basis_vectors) {

    // only accept 3 vectors
    assert(basis_vectors.size() == 3);

    // column counter
    unsigned int j = 0;

    for (auto & col : basis_vectors) {
        // copy a column (col to data[:][j])
        data[0][j] = col[0];
        data[1][j] = col[1];
        data[2][j] = col[2];

        // increase j for column
        j++;
    }
}
```

like "identifier 'data' is undefined".

**Notes**: I would like to avoid inheritance as much as I can. Weird template patterns could be nice but it's maybe better to avoid those also (otherwise everything becomes even less readable than what is now).
I would like to point out that my focus is performance, though. Therefore I am looking for the fastest and possibly cleanest solution (clean for the user that has to instantiate these classes, for example. That's why I'm using initializer lists in the constructor).

---

Side questions:

**2. What is the right syntax for specializing a constructor?**

I'm referring to: do I need to provide `template <blabla>`, or `template<>` or nothing before the method name? And what about the actual constructor method? Is it `Matrix()` or `Matrix<3>()`?

**3. Is there a way to allow my constructor to use braces list syntax when instantiating an object (to have a cleaner and uniform syntax) while enforcing at the same time a fixed size of the list?**

In my case, I would like to have a constructor that just takes 3 `Vec3` (and knows that at compile time, without `assert`ing). But I would prefer to avoid the signature `Matrix(Vec3 a, Vec3 b, Vec3 c)`. Is this possible?

**4. What's a cleaner and cahche-friendly way of doing what I'm trying to do, that is, setting columns in a 2D array?**

If this requires to change entirely my data structures, using some neat C++11/17/20/whatever `std::something`, using something that already implements nD-array slicing, or implementing that myself, I'm here ready to do all of this.

I just need some good amount of advice in all these things. It's so easy to start writing something and then to get lost into all these details and ending up writing nothing in the end, feeling that there are way too many directions where one could go and that might bring to non-optimal, non-readable, painful-to-refactor code :(

Comment: I'm no expert, but I think it's safe to say that in general you should be storing the data as a 1D-array. Then your class can present it as a 2D structure.

Comment: As to side question 2, your syntax is already correct. You can, however, not specialize just part of the class. A class specialization has no relationship to the base template. It could be a completely different class. You have to specialize the entire class.

Comment: @super what do you mean by "safe"? More comfortable to write and handle for me? More secure? More efficient?

Comment: More efficient, and probably more comfortable to write and handle as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1.

> Is it possible to just specialize a constructor in a templated class?

I suppose you are looking something as follows

```
   template <unsigned int s = size,
             std::enable_if_t< s == 3u, bool> = true>
   Matrix (std::initializer_list<Vec3> values)
    { }
```

The following is a full simplified compiling example

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <initializer_list>

struct Vec3
 { };

template <unsigned int size>
struct Matrix
 {
   // list of lists matrix constructor
   Matrix (std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<float>>)
    { }

   template <unsigned int s = size,
             std::enable_if_t< s == 3u, bool> = true>
   Matrix (std::initializer_list<Vec3> values)
    { }
 };

int main ()
 {
   Matrix<1>  m1 {{1.0f}};
   Matrix<2>  m2 {{1.0f}};
   Matrix<3>  m3 {{1.0f}};
   Matrix<4>  m4 {{1.0f}};

   //Matrix<1>  m5 {{Vec3{}}};  // compilation error
   //Matrix<2>  m6 {{Vec3{}}};  // compilation error
   Matrix<3>  m7 {{Vec3{}}};
   //Matrix<4>  m8 {{Vec3{}}};  // compilation error
 }
```

This isn't exactly "specializing a constructor"; this is "SFINAE enabling" a contructor.

---

Question 3.

> Is there a way to allow my constructor to use braces list syntax when instantiating an object (to have a cleaner and uniform syntax) while enforcing at the same time a fixed size of the list?

Not with `std::initializer_list`.

But you can obtain something similar with an good old C-style array.

```
   template <unsigned int s = size,
             std::enable_if_t< s == 3u, bool> = true>
   Matrix (Vec3 const (&values)[3u])
    { }
```

But this solution accept non only three `Vec3`'s but also one or two; the constructor receive ever an array of three with `Vec3{}` initialized with default constructor (if available) when not explicited

```
   Matrix<3>  m7a {{Vec3{}}};
   Matrix<3>  m7b {{Vec3{}, Vec3{}}};
   Matrix<3>  m7c {{Vec3{}, Vec3{}, Vec3{}}};
   //Matrix<3>  m7d {{Vec3{}, Vec3{}, Vec3{}, Vec3{}}}; // compilation error
```

**-- EDIT --**

The OP ask

> 1) should the implementation of that constructor be inside the class definition, or it can/should be outside (and with what syntax?)

I'm used to define it inside the class but, if you declare it as follows inside the class

```
   template <unsigned int s = size,
             std::enable_if_t< s == 3u, bool> = true>
   Matrix (std::initializer_list<Vec3> values);
```

defining it, outside the body of the class, as follows should works

```
template <>
template <>
Matrix<3u>::Matrix (std::initializer_list<Vec3> values)
 { }
```

> 2) This would let me pass any number of Vec3 to the constructor, while I want to be allowed to pass 3 and only 3 Vec3 in the initialization list. Is it possible to enfore this?

I don't think it's possible to enforce it, passing through `std::initializer_list`, because the number of the elements in the list isn't a template value (as in `std::array` or in a C-style array) or something that we can use compile time to enable SFINAE.

You can use the solution based on a `Vec3[3]` C-style array (see my answer to question 3) but, unfortunately, accept also one or two `Vec3`.

Comment: Thank you. This allows me to specialize the constructor just for the size==3 case. But I have a few doubts left: 1) should the implementation of that constructor be inside the class definition, or it can/should be outside (and with what syntax?). 2) This would let me pass any number of Vec3 to the constructor, while I want to be allowed to pass 3 and only 3 Vec3 in the initialization list. Is it possible to enfore this?

Comment: @MichelePiccolini - answer improved; hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, though not fully equivalent to SFINAE, is to use `static_assert`:

```
Matrix(std::initializer_list<Vec3>)
{
    static_assert(size == 3);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How does this compare with respect to using a C-style array of fixed size? Do they achieve the same effect? And do they have side effects I might want to consider (such as efficiency, readability, etc.)?

Comment: @MichelePiccolini, this question seems to be too broad for a comment. With C arrays you can enforce the number of element, with `initializer_list` you can't. Both, initializer lists and C arrays, are, in essence, just two pointers (or pointer + size), so a compiler generates similar assembly code for calling corresponding constructors. But the details can vary greatly in different situations (number of elements, whether they are known at compile time, is the constructor inlined, etc.) due to an optimizer.